# How can I view the output of a .sh file placed in rc.local?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, php, lamp

I wrote a short script to run `lampp`'s php script. It is residing on **rc.local** where I first run `opt/lampp/lampp` and then, run the sh (which is infinite) that is echoing to the output buffer infinitely.

Problem is, I don't know how to find that terminal window. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd> but did not find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just save it to a file. If you are running your script by using something like this in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/path/to/script
```

Change that to:

```
/path/to/script > /tmp/script.out 2>/tmp/script.err
```

That will create the two files `/tmp/script.out` and `/tmp/script.err` which will contain the script's output and error messages respectively.

Comment: ... and watch the output using tail -f I guess? This is useful, but I would like to see the output buffer nonetheless

Comment: @Ted I'm not at all sure there is one. If there is, you might be able to find it looking at the relevant `ps` line and seeing if a specific tty is listed. I would bet there isn't though.

Comment: Interesting! When I reboot, I CAN see the output for a second or two, then it restarts!

Comment: @Ted I don't understand what you mean. You see it where? And when? While the system is shutting down to restart or while it is starting up again?

Comment: When X closes, upon restart (when computer shuts down). Also, ps -aux shows tty1 and tty7, and when I ctrl+alt+F1 I get a login prompt only

Comment: @Ted yeah, I don't think you'll find them writing anywhere. Just use the files as I suggested.